# Snowflake ORA Auto-grader api intgegration query not executing

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am doing snowflake hands on lab exercise where I need to create DORA Auto-grader API integration. I am running the below query But seems I am getting SQL execution internal error: Processing aborted due to error 370001:1981291777; incident 9891434 error, Please help me out to fix this issue .

```
use role accountadmin;
create or replace api integration dora_api_integration
api_provider = aws_api_gateway
api_aws_role_arn = 'arn:aws:iam::321463406630:role/snowflakeLearnerAssumedRole'
enabled = true
api_allowed_prefixes = ('https://awy6hshxy4.execute-api.us-west2.amazonaws.com/dev/edu_dora');
```

Comment: This issue is something that would need support team to provide the details to relevant engineering team.

Answer (score 0):

you have a typo: `us-west2` should be `us-west-2`